# XSLT - count element and group them

Tags: xml, xslt

I need some help in XSLT transormations.

Here is XML, it's quite simple - category -> items:

```
<root isSection="true" name="videos" title="" totalElements="3">
<sections>
    <section name="NAME1" title="" order="50">
        <images />
        <sections />
        <assets />
        <resources />
    </section>
    <section name="NAME2" title="" order="50">
        <images />
        <sections />
        <assets />
        <resources />
    </section>
    <section name="Обслуживание и сервис" title="" order="50">
        <images />
        <sections />
        <assets />
        <resources />
    </section>
    <section name="NAME3" title="" order="50">
        <images />
        <sections />
        <assets>
            <asset id="1">
                <title>Охуенчик</title>
                <description>Охуенчик описание - писание - правописание (!)</description>
                <content>хуенчик</content>
            </asset>
            <asset id="2">
                <title>aaa</title>
                <description>ffff</description>
                <content>R3g1fkAqolQ</content>
            </asset>
        </assets>
        <resources />
    </section>
    <section name="NAME4" title="" order="50">
        <images />
        <sections />
        <assets>
            <asset id="3">
                <title>ggggg</title>
                <description>hhhhhhh</description>
                <content>R3g1fkAqolQ</content>
            </asset>
            <asset id="4">
                <title>asdasd</title>
                <description>asdasd</description>
                <content>SKdVq_vNAAI</content>
            </asset>
        </assets>
        <resources />
    </section>
</sections>
<assets />
<resources />
```

I need in the end of XSLT transformation have the following: XSLT counts total of all ASSET

```
<ul>
<li>TOTAL (4)</li>
<li>NAME1 (0)</li>
<li>NAME2 (0)</li>
<li>NAME3 (2)</li>
<li>NAME4 (2)</li>
</ul>
```

and the last and most problematic - is to add CLASS or ATTRIBUTE of section group to ASSET element

it'll look like:

sections -> section(NAME2) -> assets -> asset1 (add class 'NAME2') and asset2 (add class 'NAME2')

How i can do it - any ideas friends ?

Comment: The first result sample with `ul` and `li` looks like HTML to me, later in the post you ask about adding a class to an `asset` element. Therefore it is not clear to me what you want to achieve; do you want to have two different XSLT stylesheets, one that transforms the input XML into HTML, counting the `asset` elements, and a second that transforms the input XML into XML, adding an attribute to `asset` elements? As for counting `asset` elements inside of `section` elements, why is the `section` with the cyrillic name "Обслуживание и сервис" present in the input but not counted in the result?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('TOTAL (',count(.//asset),')')"/>
      </li>
      <xsl:for-each select="//section">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,' (',count(.//asset),')')"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry but I don't uderstand the second part of the question 'last and most problematic..'

Comment: Dude, you rock !
That was the 1st part of task - it's a MENU, in the 2nd part the elements of section is displayed:

 we choosed NAME3 -> and in elements (ASSET) of SECTION, needs to add class stored in attribute <section name="@this">

The second part, that planned to be is following:

`      <xsl:for-each select="//section">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="assets" />
          <A href="<<ADD CLASS TO THIS ELEMENT FROM SECTION NAME>>">@title</a>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the second part. Can you please add to your question an example of the output you want for the second part?